# jQuery ajax inside autocomplete php mysql

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get a jQuery Ajax function to work inside a Autocomplete function. The autocomplete works because it returns values, but when I select a value it doesn't do anything. I'd like to return html and display inside a div.

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $("#store").autocomplete({
        source: "includes/ajax/storenumbers.php",
        select: function(event, ui) {
            var storeid = val(ui.item.id);
            $.ajax({
               url: "includes/ajax/storecontacts.php",
               type: "GET",
               data: {term : storeid},
               dataType: "html",                               
               success: function(msg){
                            //Display html
                                $("#resultsdiv").html(msg);
                           },
                           error: function (request, status, error) {
                                alert(request.responseText);
                            }
                         });
                    }
                });
            });
```

Html:

```
<form action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>"  method="post">

<label for="store">Enter Store #: </label>

<input type="text" id="store"  name="state" /> 

<div id="resultsdiv" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;">
</div>
</form>
```

storenumbers.php return for "1":

```
[{"id":"6","value":"10211","abbrev":"Concord"},{"id":"4","value":"10869","abbrev":"Maplewood"},{"id":"5","value":"16289","abbrev":"Hugo"},{"id":"12","value":"19245","abbrev":"WBL 4th Street"}]
```

storecontacts.php return:

```
Name: Alex E-mail: alex@email.com View Order: yes Print Order: yes<br>
Name: Brooke E-mail: brooke@email.com View Order: no Print Order: no
```

I'd like the html return to eventually be a series of input text fields and check boxes. Is **dataType: html** limited to only certain things?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had to change var storeid = val(ui.item.id) to var storeid = ui.item.id;